# File Upload with progress bar in Asp.Net Mvc/ jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I am looking for a jQuery plugin for File upload with  progress bar for Asp.Net MVC. We are using RadUpload control in an existing Asp.Net WebForm application and it shows the status without using Flash/Silverlight.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/customizingraduploadui/defaultcs.aspx?RadUrid=5154cf7e-2fee-4adc-b0cc-cbe8a0da5d02

Is there any jQuery plug in available for File Upload with progress bar without using Flash/Silverlight?

**Update:** Finally found a good one.

http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Comment: Does this work for asp.net mvc? they show samples only for ruby, node.

Comment: @Amitabh, does it work for asp.net mvc?

Comment: ah, depends on the server side code, you can use "Query-File-Upload here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [jQuery Form
  Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload)
- [Ajax
  Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

Comment: `Darren Johnstone's Upload Download Module` link is gone.

Comment: so an answer is just a link?

Comment: @LuisValencia-MVP Sorry about that. This is a really old post, links were OK then I think.

Answer (score 1):

As a point of reference, the RadUpload for ASP.NET AJAX tool is able to provide the server progress bar by taking advantage of an HttpHandler and ASP.NET session state. It clearly is not ideal for web farm situations, but it's one of the only options for displaying real-time progress of a server operation on the client *without* using a plug-in (like Silverlight or Flash).

*[Side note: The "Darren" ASP.NET upload linked by Narsil is basically doing the same thing as RadUpload.]*

**The Point:** A pure jQuery upload tool will be able to provide a non-determinate progress bar (so called "infinite loop"), but will have a harder time indicating real-time progress.

Just something to keep in mind as you decide between plug-in vs. jQuery upload. For async jQuery uploading, I've used the [Ajax Upload tool](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) in the past with MVC and WebForms and enjoyed it.

Comment: RadUpload does not work well with Asp.Net Mvc. I have tried that one.