# Post Verb not allowed iis7

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, httphandler

I'm trying to implement an upload with progress bar code i found [here](https://github.com/drogus/jquery-upload-progress). But when i run my example code i get the following error in IIS7 Windows7:

[Click here for larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU1oW.png)
[image: My Error:]

I tried messing with my handlers but only messed it up more as i don't know what i'm doing. Can someone help me get this working?

Comment: Why did you mess with handlers if the code is purely client side? Please post the contents of your handlers sections.

Comment: I reverted back to original and left the handlers as they were before i messed with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your are trying to upload the file to (or trying to get process update from) a html file (`fileupload.html`) - now html files are considered as static files by IIS. So you can only issue GET request (there is no point in submitting POST to a static file because the content is not going to change based on POST data) and hence the error.

Perhaps, you have done integration incorrectly or may be using wrong plugin (the author is talking about using it in conjunction with apache module). You may want to look at alternatives from below links:

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/aspnet_file_upload_with_realti.html

[File Upload with progress bar in Asp.Net Mvc/ jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292276/file-upload-with-progress-bar-in-asp-net-mvc-jquery)

Comment: +1: yeah i think it is something about implementation... i think maybe it expects me to change the action (fileupload.html) to some handler... Anyway, you're second link was a good alternative. Went with that. http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload